# Natvis FourCC visualisation syntax

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, natvis, fourcc

I'm trying to define a .natvis <DisplayString> for a `uint32_t` type, to show as an array of four characters, which in the Watch window, during debugging, would be expressed a bit like this: `(char*)&fourcc,4`.

Unfortunately, natvis doesn't seem to like the & very much - it gets ignored, e.g. `{(char*)&fourcc,4}`, `{(char*)&{fourcc},4`, `{((char*)&)fourcc,4}` doesn't work. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects) does not make it obvious how to perform casts, if it is supported at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casts *are* supported, and the syntax is `{(char*)&amp;fourcc,4}`, i.e. use the xml entity for '&'.

For best results the `na` modifier may be used along the array size (i.e. `4` above) to suppress the showing of the memory address.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be the & HTML entity